# SDL Tridion Sites Development Platform

Tags: sdl-tridion

I really want to start SDL Tridion Sites Development. I need know about development environment and how I can connect this web content management system with development environment. Which IDE and Technologies are being used for development?

I have studied the documents available on the site but I am still confused.

Please tell me the path from where I should start as I am new to SDL Tridion Sites.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome to Tridion, and fasten your seatbelt.

I guess the best way to start is the DXA. Check the DXA documentation on https://docs.sdl.com and ask questions here.

You can use Java or .NET for this, choose whichever you feel more comfortable with.

Google for "setting up tridion development environment", you'll find a few good blog posts by the community, like [this one](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/creating-a-simple-sdl-web-8-dxa-environment).

This [one](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/9648/33) could also help.